# Loop to copy/paste until equal to last used column

Tags: excel, vba

[image]What i am trying to accomplish is upon button click the program will take the users data and copy/paste /add some formulas and other things. That part where I am running into trouble is the for loop. I would like to continue to copy/paste data until the other columns data (B:F) is equal to that last used column in column A after the for loop is complete. 
For example:

If column A is filled until row 50. I want to be able to able to see that column A is filled until row 50 and copy and paste columns(B:F) until i reach row 50.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Sheets("SourceData").Cells.Clear

Dim copySheet As Worksheet
Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet

Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("SourceData")
Set copySheet = Worksheets("SourceData")


With Sheets("Program")

    If .Range("T7").Value = "1" Then

        Worksheets("SourceData").Range("B1").Formula = "=Program!$T$12"
        Worksheets("SourceData").Range("A9:A17").Formula = "=Program!$T$8"

        Worksheets("SourceData").Range("D3").Formula = "=360/6"
        Worksheets("SourceData").Range("D4:D8").Formula = "=D3+60"
        Worksheets("SourceData").Range("D9").Formula = "=D8"
        Worksheets("SourceData").Range("D10:D15").Formula = "=D9+60"
        Worksheets("SourceData").Range("D16").Formula = "=D15"
        Worksheets("SourceData").Range("D17:D20").Formula = "=D16+360"


        Worksheets("SourceData").Range("B1").Formula = "=Program!$T$12"
        Worksheets("SourceData").Range("D1:D2,E1:E20,A1:A8,C1:C20") = "0"
        Worksheets("SourceData").Range("B2:B20").Formula = "=Program!$T$9"
        Worksheets("SourceData").Range("B16:B20").Formula = "=Program!$T$11"

        Worksheets("SourceData").Range("F1:F20").Formula = "1"

Dim val As String
val = Worksheets("Program").Range("T13").Value

 For i = 1 To val
   copySheet.Range("A9").Copy
   pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

 Next i
End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Consider using a worksheet variable or `With Worksheets("SourceData")` for better readability

Comment: It is repeatedly copying and pasting based on a user calculated number. And it does what it should, but i want to be able to see that Column A is at a certain row and continue to copy/paste a range until it reaches whatever that last active row is that was created by the For loop.

Comment: Should it still copy the value from "`copySheet.Range("A9").Copy`"? or should that part loop with the `i` in `For i = 1 To val`? I guess you want to paste A9 from B21 until say F50 if A50 is active?

Comment: if column A50 is active i want to copy a segment of data, for sake of illustration lets say its (B10:F10) and paste it until i reach A50 with that data segment, it should stop at the last active cell in column A.

Comment: Are trying to use the last row from the `Column A` in the `Program` worksheet? and insert a last row variable into the `SourceData` worksheet ranges?

Comment: Since you are pasting formulas into `Columns B and D`. How do you expect to manage the different formulas when you "paste columns(B:F) until i reach row 50" ?

Answer (score 0):

Just to note, you are creating variable `val` as a string and then using it as a number. Better to Dim it as Long or Integer.

If you want to get the number of filled cells in column A, use `count = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("SourceData").Range("A:A"))`.

The following loop will go through all rows with data in column A, separating rows with data from rows without.

```
Dim i As Long, count As Long
count = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("SourceData").Range("A:A"))
i = 0
Do While count > 0
    i = i + 1
    If Sheets("SourceData").Range("A" & CStr(i)).Value2 <> "" Then
        count = count - 1
        ... {process row with data}
    Else
        ... {process row without data?}
    End If
Loop
```

Comment: How does this answer the OP's question? The question is not clear enough to know that the OP wants to count only filled cells. With out clarification from the OP we don't know what he/she is trying to accomplish.

Comment: Based on the questioner's statement of "If column A is filled until row 50. I want to be able to able to see that column A is filled until row 50 and copy and paste columns(B:F) until i reach row 50." I understood this to mean they wanted their copy function to copy to all rows from the first to the last with data in column A. Being that their question was a bit vague, I included method to not copy to blank rows in case this was part of their issue.

Comment: I actually think the OP was trying to identify the last row in column A on `Sheets("Program")`; but like i said we don't have enough information to provide a usable answer.

Comment: I added a picture to try and help explain/ clarify this a little more. I want to copy and past a segment of data in Range (B2:F5)  and paste it until i reach Column A's last active cell. Column A will always be filled with something, there will be no blank cells.

Comment: @Bradley, In this case, my answer will work to get the row of last cell in column A with data (what you are calling "active"). After the Do ... Loop completes, `i` will be equal to the last row. As for copying, I'm not sure exactly what it is you're copying. Values? Formulas? You are copying 4 rows, what do you do when there is only one row remaining active? One suggestion - use the record macro feature of excel and look at the code it generates when you manually copy and modify it as needed. If you still need help, please give a full description of how you would manually copy.